# Clear Text Input data once submit button clicked in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I want to clear the text after submitting the val in the Text Input in the react-native code 
Here is my code

```
export default function AddTodo({onSubmit}) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const changeHandler = (val) => {
        setText(val)
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.newInput}
                placeholder="Add task"
                onChangeText={changeHandler}
            />
            <Button onPress={() => onSubmit(text)} title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a value attribute to your TextInput like this

```
<TextInput
                style={styles.newInput}
                placeholder="Add task"
                onChangeText={changeHandler}
                value = {text}
            />
```

And then clear the text when on submit like this

```
  <Button onPress={() => {
            onSubmit(text)
            setText('') }} title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />
```

Total code will be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import  {useState} from 'react';
export default function AddTodo({onSubmit}) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const changeHandler = (val) => {
        console.log("val is",val);
        setText(val)
    }

    return (
        <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Add task"
                onChangeText={changeHandler}
                value={text}
            />
            <Button onPress={() => {
                onSubmit(text)
                setText('') }} title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Call no arg onSubmit()

```
<Button onPress={() => onSubmitAndClear(text)} title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />

    const onSubmitAndClear() = (text) => {
            setText(text)
         /// after submit operation then clear

          setText('')
        }
```

Comment: check the syntax, there are some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet for your problem with the solution.

```
export default function AddTodo({onSubmit}) {
const [text, setText] = useState('')
const changeHandler = (val) => {
    setText(val)
}

const handleSumit = () => {
    // perform the summit operation
    setText("");
}
return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.newInput}
            placeholder="Add task"
            onChangeText={changeHandler}
        />
        <Button onPress={handleSumit} title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />
    </View>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use ref of your `TextInput` , and assign your text directly it like

```
refOfTextInput.setNativeProps({ text: "hello world" })
```

to the get the ref of `TextInput` you can use this approach

```
<TextInput ref={(ref) => { this.refOfTextInput = ref; }} />
```

so inside your text callback or any other component if you have ref of your `TextInput` you can use it like

```
        const onSubmitAndClear() = (text) => {
            refOfTextInput.setNativeProps({ text: "hello world" })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

add this function:

```
const clear = () {
  setText('')
}
```

and then:

```
<Button onPress={() => {onSubmit(text), clear()} } title="Add Task" color='#1881e9' />
```