# Clear text input with button press with minimum rendering - React Native functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to have my TextInput components cleared when I press a submit button.
I am using functional components and the accepted answer posted here worked for me:
[Clear Text Input data once submit button clicked in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430293/clear-text-input-data-once-submit-button-clicked-in-react-native)

However, I realized that my component is rendered every time I enter a single character in the TextInput. I assume this could cause performance issues if my component gets bigger.

Is there a way to reduce the number of renders in this case?

Comment: Usually the performance impact won‘t be too serious in this case.
But in case you wanna tweak everything, you could use ref/useRef to reach your goal (https://www.codebeast.dev/usestate-vs-useref-re-render-or-not/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the text via the textinputs ref. This way it won't trigger a rerender.

```
const inputRef=useRef()
const submit=()=>{
   // Clears the text
   inputRef.current.setNativeProps({ text: "" });
}
```